# How to build buildOutputValue method

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Please, i need help in this code:

```
public class ThirdQueryReducer extends
    Reducer<IntWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text> {

private NullWritable nullWritableKey = NullWritable.get();
private Text outputValue = new Text();

private StringBuilder buildOutputValue(IntWritable key,
        StringBuilder reduceValueBuilder, Text value) {


}

@Override
public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {


}}
```

How i coul implement the buildOutputValue? knowing that the output in mapper is like this: `mapDriver.withOutput(new IntWritable(1981), new Text("Mercurey"));`

And the buildOutputValue() must to process dates like this:

`List<Text> values = new ArrayList<Text>();
 values.add(new Text("Pommard"));
 values.add(new Text("Gentil"));
 reduceDriver.withInput(new IntWritable(1980), values);`

And the output in the reducer is like this:

`reduceDriver.withOutput(NullWritable.get(), new Text("Pommard\nGentil"));`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it like below :

public class ThirdQueryReducer extends
        Reducer {

```
private NullWritable nullWritableKey = NullWritable.get();
private Text outputValue = new Text();

private StringBuilder buildOutputValue(IntWritable key,
        StringBuilder reduceValueBuilder, Text value) {
    return reduceValueBuilder.append(value);
}

@Override
public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Iterator<Text> valueIter = values.iterator();
    StringBuilder reduceValueBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    while (valueIter.hasNext()) {
        buildOutputValue(key, valueIter.next(), reduceValueBuilder);
        if (valueIter.hasNext()) {
            reduceValueBuilder.append("\n");
        }
    }
    context.write(NullWritable.get(), new Text(reduceValueBuilder.toString()));
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, this is a great alternative!